# Google Search Analytics in Search Console shows almost no data while Google Analytics reports plenty of organic traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, search-analytics

I don't understand why I don't see any break down of my pages in search analytics, even though:

- 46 pages currently indexed by google.com
- Google Analytics shows around 100 daily unique visitors
- Around 50% of trafic is organic
- Site has been continuously live for years
- Site is a webapp with `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

[image: Screenshot of search analytics > pages]

## What are the possible causes?

I was wondering if it could be related to the `sitemap.xml`, but after fixing it problem persists.

Comment: That isn't "no data".   Your home page is listed there.    You are getting 0, 1 or 2  clicks each day and they are all to your home page.  Do you have all four variations of your site added as properties to Google Search Console?  That is both www and no-www, http and https.

Comment: I had http and https but missed no-www. Added them as property and I now have a set of 4 (www and no-www, http and https). Google says it has not processed any data yet for no-www and https, though now I do have 57 pages showing up in Search Analytics > Pages of the set. Should I now work only on the set to analyze my traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main causes for so little data in Google Search Console:

#### You need to wait

Google Search Console often takes a week or two to show data when you first create a property.   Even once a property is up and running, new data sometimes takes several days to become visible.

#### Your traffic isn't on that property

You may have added `https://example.com` to Google Search Console, but Google is actually sending traffic to `https://www.example.com`.   Subdomains don't "roll up" in GSC, nor does HTTP to HTTPS.   If you are missing traffic you should add all your variations as separate properties:

- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`

If you have other subdomains such as a blog, you will need to also add them separately: `https://blog.example.com`

For more information on this practice of adding many properties for your site, see [Should I submit https:// and https://www in webmaster tools?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83685/should-i-submit-https-and-https-www-in-webmaster-tools) and [How do the combinations of http/https and naked/www in Google Search Console work?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87941/how-do-the-combinations-of-http-https-and-naked-www-in-google-search-console-wor)

Once you have all these properties added, you can create a single view in GSC that combines all of them.  This is called a [property set](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6338828?hl=en).   Property sets will show most of the combined data from your individual properties, however some reports are not available against property sets.

Another way to get around the problem is to canonicalize your URLs.  Choose a preferred version of your site and redirect all the other variations to it.  Once you do so, Google will start sending all traffic to your preferred URL within a few weeks.   Here are some instructions for various server configurations:

- [Properly redirect a site to WWW and HTTPS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104475/properly-redirect-a-site-to-www-and-https)
- [How do I use IIS7 rewrite to redirect requests for (HTTP or HTTPS):// (www or no-www) .domainaliases.ext to HTTPS://maindomain.ext](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35095/how-do-i-use-iis7-rewrite-to-redirect-requests-for-http-or-https-www-or-no)
- [https:// redirect to https://www in NGINX](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104089/https-redirect-to-https-www-in-nginx)

You could also use [rel canonical link tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#rel-canonical-link-method) rather than redirects if it would be easier.

---

I don't think it is related to your problem, but you say you use `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`. That is part of Google's AJAX crawling scheme which [Google deprecated years ago](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html).   You should switch to normal crawling for your AJAX content now because Googlebot now ignores that meta tag.   Googlebot is trying to crawl your content and render the JavaScript now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be that you haven't synced the analytics with Google Search Console:

[image]

For this See how to [Access Search Console Data in Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1120006?utm_source=wnc_795001&utm_medium=gamma&utm_campaign=wnc_795001&utm_content=msg_889302&hl=en).

Vice versa you can also [Configure Search Console data in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1308621?hl=en)